# Export embedded resources from C# assembly?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I have a C# dll that has some embedded resources and i'm having troubles with a couple of them. What would be the best app's to pull these resources out so that I can check them over?

Comment: Be careful to never be successful at what you do.  Because if you are, whomever owns the copyright to these resources is going to hurt you.  Typical copyright infringement awards are all profits + damages + penalty.

Comment: They are our own dlls. They were compiled at an earlier date with different embedded resources than we have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that opening the file with .Net Reflector allowed me to see the Resources!

Answer (score 1):

Try [DotNetResourcesExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dot_net_resources_extract.html)

UPDATE: 
Seems like doesn't work with .Net 3.5 files.
Try [Resource Tuner](http://www.restuner.com/). Looks promising and it has a 30 day fully functional trial version available for download.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to be extracting the files. I'm thinking it may be becuase the target dll is .Net 3.5, but not 100% sure.